# Reading xml file from a resource

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am trying to load an xml file that is stored as a resource in my C# project so I can perform various LINQ queries.  However at runtime an "Illegal characters in path" exception is thrown.  This is how I am loading the file:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(MyProject.Properties.Resources.XMLFile);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wouldn't `XMLFile` here actually return the xml itself? If so:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(MyProject.Properties.Resources.XMLFile);
```